# Vendor vs Provider confusion

Tags: cloud

i am a newbie to cloud computing and studying for Comptia CLOUD+ Exam.
I am confused between Vendor and Provider.
it says in the book that vendor sells solutions to customer.I am not able to figure out like what solutions.. how is it different from providers?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms,

**Cloud Vendors** are those who provide a software/applications/service using cloud resources from cloud provider. The customers can use the software/applications/service developed by cloud vendor directly, sometimes these software/applications/service SaaS(Software as a Service). e.g. [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/),[Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/).

**Cloud Providers** are those companies who  provides cloud computing resources, who have a huge infrastructure for cloud computing in form of data-centers. These companies provides Infrastructure and Platform to cloud vendors as well as general public or whosoever wishes to have. The provision of raw hardware resources often known as IaaS(Infrastructure as a Service) and sometimes they provide platform for developing and deploying cloud based applications known as PaaS(Platform as a Service). e.g.- [Companies at Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us),[Companies at AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace)